# Search list of ids in a log file in unix

Tags: unix, awk, grep

Sorry to ask this, might be a trivial question,  tried awk script as well. But I think I am new to that.

I have a list of Ids in a file i.e. `ids.txt`

```
1xre23
223dsf
234ewe
```

and a log file with FIX messages which might contain those ids.
sample: log file `abc.log`

```
35=D^A54=1xre23^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
35=D^A54=abcd23^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
35=D^A54=234ewe^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
35=D^A54=xyzw23^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
35=D^A54=223dsf^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
```

I want to check how many ids matched in that log file. 
Ids are large almost 10K, and log file size is around 300MB. 
sample output I am looking for is.

output:

```
35=D^A54=1xre23^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
35=D^A54=234ewe^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
35=D^A54=223dsf^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like with grep command:

```
grep -w -f ids.txt abc.log
Output:
35=D^A54=1xre23^A22=s^A120=GBP^A<br>
35=D^A54=234ewe^A22=s^A120=GBP^A<br>
35=D^A54=223dsf^A22=s^A120=GBP^A<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use `awk` this should do:

```
awk -F"[=^]" 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} $4 in a' ids.txt abc.log
35=D^A54=1xre23^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
35=D^A54=234ewe^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
35=D^A54=223dsf^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
```

This store the `ids.txt` in array `a`
If fourth field (separated by `=` and  `^`) contains the ID, print it.

---

You can also do it the other way around:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} {for (i in a) if ($0~i) print}' abc.log ids.txt
35=D^A54=1xre23^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
35=D^A54=234ewe^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
35=D^A54=223dsf^A22=s^A120=GBP^A
```

Store all data from `abc.log` in array  `a`
Then test if line contains data for `id.txt`
If yes, print the line.